# Layout_Weight giving unexpected results

Tags: android-layout

So I'm trying to have three sections on my screen. A top "toolbar"-esque thing that takes up 10% of the screen. Data that I will later fill which takes up 70% of the screen and finally 20% of the screen for a search bar at the bottom.

I would think that this would be a simple thing to do: a linear layout with 3 linear layout children that have a weight of 0.1, 0.7 and 0.2 respectively. However, that's not working. When I change the layout_weight of some views, it changes the amount of screen that other views take up. Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.95"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This gives me a first empty layout that takes up 20% of the screen (yes, with a 0.95 weight), the second empty layout takes up 80% of the screen and the final layout is empty. When I give the final layout a weight of, say, 0.1, it then gives the first layout a bit more space. I presume I have some rogue formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [layout_weight documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight):

> This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view.

In other words, it indicates the percentage of remaining space that a layout can take.
If you wan't to distribute the space in those proportions then you should first assign a height of 0 to your `LinearLayouts` (indicating that all the screen is free space).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```